# Nested functions have access to the scope "above" them...but does it matter where they were defined?

Tags: javascript, closures, local-variables, node-modules, scoping

I always thought that nested *function invocations* had access to the scope above them regardless of where the function was *defined* (in the below example I thought the `printsomething` function would have access to the "something" variable in the `runeverything` function). According to the below fiddle this is not the case. Does the function `printsomething` have to be defined (and not just invoked) within the outer function `runeverything` to have access to local variables defined within the other function `runeverything`?

This is important for me now because node modules are hoisted to the top when they are imported. This creates scoping problems for me!

```js
function foo(){
function printsomething() {
  $('#test').text(something || 'nothing');
};
  
var something = 'something';

function runeverything() {
  
  printsomething(); //returns "something is not defined"
}

runeverything();
};

foo();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
```

Comment: What's the question? What you've found with your test is correct: JavaScript has static lexical scoping. The point in the code at which a function is declared definitely matters.

Comment: What can I do in node when the module imports are hoisted to the top? When I invoke a method from the module I have to pass all the variables as options because the method cannot access the variables of the outer function. Is there some sort of solution for this?

Comment: Again, JavaScript has static lexical scope. There's no "solution" for that - it's the fundamental nature of the language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Scope is determined by where the function is defined and **not** by where it is called from.

To get access to data from the scope where a function is called: pass it as an argument.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting tired of passing huge "options" objects when I invoke functions from other modules in node (functions from other scripts that I required). Do you have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have those functions embedded in another function in order to do that:
i.e:

```
function foo() {
    function printsomething() {
        $('#test').text(something || 'nothing');
    };

    function runeverything() {
        printsomething(); //returns "something"
    }

    var something = 'something';
    runeverything();
};
foo();
```

This way it will work since the scope of variable something is for function foo, where your functions are defined also.

Comment: I edited my snippet above. Try running it. The outer "foo" function doesn't solve the issue. I thought it would too and that really confused me.

Comment: You still have your var something defined in runeverything function. you need to have it defined in foo function

Comment: Oh, you're right. My bad. Thanks for catching that. Unfortunately it looks like the code that I'm importing in node via "require" is always hoisted to the very top above any outer function! In the context I am working in unfortunately this won't work but you still get the up vote because this totally answers the question I asked.

Comment: why dont you create a single object with all the variables as properties of the object and only pass that object when you invoke functions? i.e. var obj={var1: 'abc',var2:'def'}; invokeFunction(obj)

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that :)